# Swift sort a NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, sorting, nsmanagedobject

I want to sort a NSManagedObject fetched from CoreData. I already have NSSortDescriptor when i fetch results. However, results come from two different fetch requests. I combine then again in a array of NSManagedObjet. I would like to sort that array in ascending order.

There is

```
 NAManagedObject.sorted(by: (NSManagedObject, NSManagedObject) throws -> bool)
```

Not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is called results, it might be something like this:

```
    let sortedArray = results.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
        return first.value > value.value
    }
```

...where 'value' is the value you want to sort by. This would give a descending sort - you basically want to return true if 'first' should appear before 'second' in the resulting list.

Comment: I am not sure if i can do first.value because it is also a NSManagedObject.

Comment: Well, just chain down. `first.item.value` for example.